# Security of secrets added to next.config.js

Tags: next.js, auth0, vercel

We are working adding Auth0 to our Next.js website and referencing [this](https://github.com/brettski/next.js/tree/canary/examples/auth0) example.

What I am wondering about is the settings in [next.config.js](https://github.com/brettski/next.js/blob/canary/examples/auth0/next.config.js#L8) in the example. It puts the Auth0 and other **secrets** in the client (via Webpack). Doesn't this put these secrets at risk? Since they are somewhere in the client code, there is a chance that a request can be made to access the secrets.

Examples [in this Auth0 article](https://auth0.com/blog/ultimate-guide-nextjs-authentication-auth0/#Next-js-Serverless-Deployment-Model) also puts the secrets in the client.

I haven't had much luck finding out how Webpack handles the variables and am looking to the community to shed some light on this. We are trying to ensure our pattern is safe before putting it in to place.

From example, secrets being added to client side `next.config.js`:

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()

module.exports = {
  env: {
    AUTH0_DOMAIN: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
    AUTH0_CLIENT_ID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
    AUTH0_SCOPE: 'openid profile',
    REDIRECT_URI:
      process.env.REDIRECT_URI || 'http://localhost:3000/api/callback',
    POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI:
      process.env.POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI || 'http://localhost:3000/',
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECRET: process.env.SESSION_COOKIE_SECRET,
    SESSION_COOKIE_LIFETIME: 7200, // 2 hours
  },
}
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Update - Next v9.4:

Since Next.js v9.4, it exposes only env variables with the prefix `NEXT_PUBLIC_` to the **browser**.
For more info, [read this](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser)

---

#### Original answer:

**DON'T** put any secret env variables in a place that is accessible to the client.

I'm not sure what next does with this `env` property, It just [configures](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/9b6ea9d466213361228e9da0d4da8e58abbbcc29/packages/next/build/webpack-config.ts#L652-L664) a webpack `DefinePlugin` that replaces usages of `process.env.VAR` to it's value.

So, this means that your secrets will be inside bundles that are **public**.

To confirm that it is exposed in the client,

1. open dev-tools
2. open console by
   pressing <kbd>esc</kbd>
3. click on the `search` tab
4. enter your secret key

It will find it in one of the bundles.

Comment: Thank you @felixmosh for the response. I have actually done that search. The only time a search is positive is when `process.env.VAR` is called explicitly. Otherwise they don't appear. Which I find strange. This is why I opened this question, to get some clarity on all of this. Auth0 uses nextjs for their site, and Zeit, uses Auth0 for theirs. This is the example they provide, and to me does seem insecure.

Comment: This is make sense, if you are not using the variable itself DefinePlugin won't replace it to its value. BUT, it make a mistake of exposing sensitive data one step.